# Intellij IDEA: Ultimate to Tomcat7 server

Tags: gwt, tomcat, deployment, intellij-idea

How do I deploy my GWT application that I created in intellij IDEA: Ultimate to a remote tomcat server?   The only thing that I have thought of was to upload the .war file through the manager app, but I can't figure out how to compile the .war file...

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: I do not know if you can create .war file with idea. I am also fan of idea. What I do is I explode all war file content to out path and with ant script(3-4 line) I create a war file from out folder. That is what I used to do. Here is simple example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ant/ant_creating_war_files.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working like this:

Use webAppCreator to create webapp

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/RefCommandLineTools

(Pass it the -maven flag)

Then, in Intellij, create a new project over existing sources...

import the maven project, clean.

maven deploy creates the war file.

Login to tomcat manager, upload the war file.

Comment: Are you not using any build tool like maven?? Maven provides the plugins to do the same. It might seem difficult but it gets awesome as you go!!!